# Bind all company completion to <Tab>

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, company-mode

I am bit confused about different company completion modes. How can I make company always accept completion by  instead of ?

Currently these three commands I use most:

1. `company-complete-selection`
2. `company-complete-common`
3. `company-template-forward-field`

Is it possible to bind all of them to single key based on context? As it is in Sublime or VS code?

I tried adding to my `init.el`

```
(bind-key*  "<tab>" 'company-complete-selection)
(bind-key*  "<tab>" 'company-complete-common)
```

But it only takes the first binding.

Also can I ensure that comapny-mode completely ignores ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [company-mode manual](http://company-mode.github.io/manual/Overview.html#Structure):

> Company is bundled with an alternative workflow configuration
> *company-tng* — defining `company-tng-frontend`, `company-tng-mode`, and
> `company-tng-map` — that allows performing completion with just <kbd>TAB</kbd>. To
> enable this configuration, add the following line to the Emacs
> initialization file

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'company-tng-mode)
```

To explore `company-tng` documentation in more detail, use the command that extracts *Commentary* section from its source file:

`M-x finder-commentary` <kbd>RET</kbd> `company-tng` <kbd>RET</kbd>

A related [Company Discussion](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/discussions/1193) provides links for more information on the topic.